# django: submit POST to create objects not working

Tags: javascript, django, twitter-bootstrap

Updates:

I made sure that when clicking submit button, the page is not even reloading.

So I tried to fill out the form and view source code on page. I had the form like this:
[image]

and the source code show the following:

```
 <div id="logModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">

         <div class="modal-header">
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
           <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Log In or Out </h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">


             <form method='POST' action='' >
              <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='LcLKE7jeFQWslds3i6vFM3MdBlIK26Pie2pIu5DYK68jCjzggfO7y1rjKrrZqKcc' />



<form  method="post" > <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='LcLKE7jeFQWslds3i6vFM3MdBlIK26Pie2pIu5DYK68jCjzggfO7y1rjKrrZqKcc' /> <link href="/static/css/datetimepicker.css" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script> <div id="div_id_in_or_out" class="form-group"> <label for="id_in_or_out" class="control-label ">
                In or out
            </label> <div class="controls "> <select class="select form-control" id="id_in_or_out" name="in_or_out">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="IN">IN</option>
<option value="OUT">OUT</option>
</select> </div> </div> <div id="div_id_logout_date" class="form-group"> <label for="logout_date" class="control-label  requiredField">
                Log Date<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="controls "> <div id="logout_date" class="input-group date"> <input class="datewidget form-control" id="logout_date" name="logout_date" type="text" value="2017-01-10" required /> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span> </div> <script type="text/javascript">
           $("#logout_date").datetimepicker({minView: 2,
autoclose: true,
language: 'en',
format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
startView: 2}).find('input').addClass("form-control");
       </script> </div> </div> <div id="div_id_logout_by" class="form-group"> <label for="id_logout_by" class="control-label ">
                Log by
            </label> <div class="controls "> <input class="textinput textInput form-control" id="id_logout_by" maxlength="200" name="logout_by" type="text" /> </div> </div> <div id="div_id_out_shipping_method_tracking_number" class="form-group"> <label for="id_out_shipping_method_tracking_number" class="control-label ">
                Shipping method and tracking number
            </label> <div class="controls "> <input class="textinput textInput form-control" id="id_out_shipping_method_tracking_number" maxlength="200" name="out_shipping_method_tracking_number" type="text" /> </div> </div> <div id="div_id_out_notes" class="form-group"> <label for="id_out_notes" class="control-label ">
                Out notes
            </label> <div class="controls "> <textarea class="textarea form-control" cols="40" id="id_out_notes" name="out_notes" rows="10">
</textarea> </div> </div> </form>

              <input type="submit" value="Submit">
              <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default" name = "logform">Save</button>

             </form>



         </div>
           <div class="modal-footer">
           <!--         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">close</button> -->
           </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Apparently my inputs are not showing up, and what really confuses me is this: <"name="logout_date" type="text" value="2017-01-10">

where does this value come from.....!?

---

So I am trying to do something like this:

[image]

the user checks the checkbox to select which pieces of sample he or she would like to create logout record for, and then click the logout button. Then it jumps to another page with Bootstrap Modal showing the logout form like the following:

[image]

My problem is, after filling out the forms and click SAVE, there is just nothing happening. I will post my relevant code here with some explanation about what I tried.

Logout model:

```
class Logout(models.Model):
    sample = models.ForeignKey(SampleDetail, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True)
    in_or_out = models.CharField(max_length = 200, choices = INOUT_CHOCIES, null=True, blank = True)
    logout_date =  models.DateField(verbose_name = 'log date', null=True, blank = True)
    logout_by = models.CharField(max_length = 200, verbose_name = 'log by', null=True, blank = True)
    out_shipping_method_tracking_number = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'shipping method and tracking number')
    out_notes= models.CharField(max_length = 200, verbose_name = 'notes', null=True, blank = True)
```

Logout Form:

```
class LogOutForm(ModelForm):
    logout_date=forms.DateField(widget=DateWidget(attrs={'id':"logout_date"}, usel10n = True, bootstrap_version=3), initial=datetime.date.today, label="Log Date")
    out_notes = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)


    class Meta:
        model = Logout
        fields = ['in_or_out', 'logout_date','logout_by', 'out_shipping_method_tracking_number','out_notes']
```

update_sample_logout View.py:

```
def update_sample_logout (request, project_id):

    if 'loglist' in request.GET:
        sample_detail_list = request.GET.getlist('loglist')
        samples = SampleDetail.objects.filter(id__in = sample_detail_list)
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Did not select sample" )
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('projstatus:project_detail', args=(project_id,)))


    project = Project.objects.get(id = project_id)

    log_form = LogOutForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)


    if request.method == 'POST':
        if log_form.is_valid():
            in_or_out = log_form.cleaned_data['in_or_out']
            logout_date = log_form.cleaned_data['logout_date']
            logout_by = log_form.cleaned_data['logout_by']
            out_shipping_method_tracking_number = log_form.cleaned_data['out_shipping_method_tracking_number']
            out_notes = log_form.cleaned_data['out_notes']
            for sample in samples:
                record = Logout.objects.create(sample = sample, in_or_out = in_or_out, logout_date = logout_date,
                logout_by = logout_by, out_shipping_method_tracking_number = out_shipping_method_tracking_number,
                out_notes = out_notes )
                record.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('projstatus:project_detail', args=(project_id,)))



    context = {'project' : project, "log_form":log_form}
    return render(request, 'projstatus/detail_log.html', context)
```

logout template:

```
<div id="logModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">

         <div class="modal-header">
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
           <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Log In or Out </h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">


             <form method='POST' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
              {% csrf_token %}
              {{ log_form.management_form}}
              {% crispy log_form %}
              <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default" name = "logform">Save</button>

             </form>



         </div>
           <div class="modal-footer">
           <!--         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">close</button> -->
           </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>                

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {

   if(window.location.href.indexOf('#logModal') != -1) {
     $('#logModal').modal('show');
   }

 }); 

 $(function(){

     $('#logModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
         window.location.href = "{% url 'projstatus:project_detail' project.id %}";
     });

 });
 </script>
```

What I am doing here is a bit circuitous. projstatus:project_detail is the main page for details of a project and you select those samples that you would like to log out there (like in the first picture). And then when you click the logout button, it serves as a submit for

```
<form id="checklist" action="{% url 'projstatus:update_sample_logout' project.id %}#logModal" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

so update_sample_logout got user's selection and get corresponding samples.

The two sections of javascript in template is to make sure that when jumped to update_sample_logout, the Modal is always showing up, and also when user close the Modal without submitting, it brings the user back to project_detail.

So I tried to do a bit of debugging by putting a print(" It runs through here") right under 'if request.method == 'POST':". And then tried to submit the form by clicking SAVE, but still nothing happened, not even the print. So it seems that in update_sample_logout, it doesn't even recognize the form POST. What does this mean? Could this be caused by the form data I put in doesn't validate? Which I doubt since I tried many times.

Also I did make sure that the samples selection passed to update_sample_logout by GET is working correctly. samples actually contains whatever user selected.

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow these steps to figure out the reason:

1. Make sure, when  you click the Submit button, the page is reloaded;
2. Check the page source code to make sure the content of the form is correct;
3. Before you click the submit button, make sure every field in the logout page is valued and the value is correct;
4. Change your code and add "else" section as below:

   def update_sample_logout (request, project_id):

   ```
   if request.method == 'GET':
       ......

   project = Project.objects.get(id = project_id)

   log_form = LogOutForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
   if request.method == 'POST':
       if log_form.is_valid():
           ......
       ***else:
           # go to another page or print out some information you can see.***
   ```
5. If everything above is working, you can comment out the this section as below:

   ```
   if log_form.is_valid():
       # in_or_out = log_form.cleaned_data['in_or_out']
       # logout_date = log_form.cleaned_data['logout_date']
       # logout_by = log_form.cleaned_data['logout_by']
       # out_shipping_method_tracking_number =  log_form.cleaned_data['out_shipping_method_tracking_number']
       # out_notes = log_form.cleaned_data['out_notes']
   ```

AND released one by one to test which is not correct.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks a dozen for all the help! I updated the problem to reflect some progress and new problems.

Comment: So after deleting this logout model and create a new model which is in essence identical to it, it works. I am really not sure why, probably a glitch in django. Anyway, Thanks!

Comment: Me neither. There are a lot of strange problems we do not know the reason. BUT anyway, it is working.  Congratulations!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that there is nothing wrong with your code.

I believe that you loose `loglist` GET parameter at some point, so the view just redirect you to "projstatus:project_detail" page.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this section:

```
if 'loglist' in request.GET:
    sample_detail_list = request.GET.getlist('loglist')
    samples = SampleDetail.objects.filter(id__in = sample_detail_list)
else:
    messages.error(request, "Did not select sample" )
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('projstatus:project_detail', args=(project_id,)))
```

So, when you finished the form and click the "SAVE" button, the method for request is "POST", then the page will go to the `projstatus:project_detail`.

if you want to check the method in the same method, you can use like this:

```
def update_sample_logout (request, project_id):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        if 'loglist' in request.GET:
            sample_detail_list = request.GET.getlist('loglist')
            samples = SampleDetail.objects.filter(id__in = sample_detail_list)
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Did not select sample" )
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('projstatus:project_detail', args=(project_id,)))


    project = Project.objects.get(id = project_id)

    log_form = LogOutForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)


    if request.method == 'POST':
        if log_form.is_valid():
            ......
```

Comment: Thanks so much for catching that for me! Unfortunately, however, the SAVE button is still not working: clicking it just has no effect and the form is not submitted.

Comment: I mean, even before this fix, clicking the submit doesn't do anything like jumping to projstatus:project_detail. Which is really weird

Comment: OK, I give you a new answer